# Styling datagrid doesn't work

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am trying to style my own datagrid and here's what I am doing:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid_1" Margin="554,92,52,373" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  >
            <DataGridRow>
                <DataGridRow.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF878787" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </DataGridRow.Background>
            </DataGridRow>
            <DataGridColumnHeader>
                <DataGridColumnHeader.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </DataGridColumnHeader.Background>
            </DataGridColumnHeader>
            <DataGridCell>
                <DataGridCell.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF878787" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </DataGridCell.Background>
                <DataGridCell.BorderBrush>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </DataGridCell.BorderBrush>
            </DataGridCell>
            <DataGridRowHeader>
                <DataGridRowHeader.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </DataGridRowHeader.Background>
            </DataGridRowHeader>

        </DataGrid>
```

The thing is it just doesn't change the default style, and I really don't know what is the problem, I think I'm doing everything right. Any help out here pls? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ya, it might be beneficial to take a look at one of the numerous articles on styling a wpf datagrid available out on the internet. You'll likely see what you're doing wrong pretty quickly from any one of them. After that if you have a more specific question, then this is the place.

Comment: You're adding `Items` to the `DataGrid`, not changing `Styles`. I suggest you read up on WPF basics before trying to customize Styles and/or Templates.

Comment: here is a good article about styling DataGrid http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/01/20/styling-microsoft-s-wpf-datagrid.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to set style to your DATAGRID..

This is just an example so that you can start and get your own DatagridStyle.

```
 <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```